# Chatbot not sending message back in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot, microsoft-teams

For an azure chatbot I want it to ask me a simple question after its answer, so I can for example give feedback in return. 
I am using the `HeroCard` class.

**dialog**

```
private async Task ShowWeatherResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
    {
        if (entity.Type.Equals(Entity_Location))
        {
            WeatherAPI weather = new WeatherAPI(entity.Entity);
            found = true;
            await context.PostAsync(weather.ForecastReport());
            await Task.Delay(500);

            // ask for happiness
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
                Content = CardsBuilder.CreateHappinessCard()
            };
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();
            reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            await context.PostAsync(reply, CancellationToken.None);

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"I don't speak human fluently, try another question asking for a specific city!");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
}


public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    if (message.Text != null)
    {
        //
        var happiness = new HappinessAPI();

        // Got an Action Submit
        string value = message.Text;
        //string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
        switch (value)
        {
            case "ShowGif":
                await context.PostAsync(happiness.ShowGif(context), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.Delay(500);
                break;
            case "HappinessSearch":
                await context.PostAsync(happiness.GetJoke(context), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.Delay(500);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

**HerdoCard**

```
    internal static HeroCard CreateHappinessCard()
    {
        HeroCard card = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Hi!",
            Text = "Are you happy?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Yes",
                    Text = "Yes",
                    DisplayText = "Yes",
                    Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
                    Value = "ShowGif"
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Meh...",
                    Text ="No",
                    DisplayText = "Meh...",
                    Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
                    Value = "HappinessSearch"
                }
            }

        };

        return card;
    }
```

**happinessapi**

```
public class HappinessAPI
{
    internal IMessageActivity ShowGif(IDialogContext context)
    {
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
            Content = new HeroCard()
            {
                Images = new List<CardImage>()
                {
                    new CardImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/220px-Smiley.svg.png")
                }
            }
        };
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        return reply;
    }

    internal IMessageActivity GetJoke(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Text = (string)(JObject.Parse(text))["value"]["joke"];

        return reply;
    }
}
```

Thing is, it works while testing using the WebChat in AzurePortal but the responseback to its questions doesn't in microsoft teams.

Sample:
`Works in Webchat:`

Me: weather in Frankfurt

Bot: "It's cold.... whatever"

Bot: Are you happy?

Me: click "yes/no"

Bot: Sends a joke or a smiley
[image]

`Doesn't work in Microsoft Teams`

Everything is ok until I click "yes/no", then it just tris to do something(the "is typing..." appears but after that, nothing happens.
[image]

*EDIT*

I see while using the Chatbot in Microsoft Teams when I click the herocard a message is written in the chat, when it shouldn't, because it was set to ActionTypes.Postback

*EDIT 2*

The HeroCard now looks like this:

```
    internal static HeroCard CreateHappinessCard()
    {
        HeroCard card = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Hi!",
            Text = "Are you happy?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Yes",
                    Text = "ShowGif",
                    //DisplayText = null,
                    Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                    Value= "{\"action\": \"ShowGif\" }"
                },
                new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = "Meh...",
                    Text ="HappinessSearch",
                    //DisplayText = null,
                    Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                    Value = "{\"action\": \"HappinessSearch\" }"
                }
            }

        };

        return card;
    }
}
```

But still not working. No message is sent back to the bot. If I use `imBack` type it does, but the message appears in the chat, what I don't want and `messageBack` is supposed to work.

*EDIT 3* following the code provided

**dialog**

```
    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. You said: {result.Query}");

        context.Call(new HeroCardDialog(), MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        if (message != null)
        {
            //

        }

        //context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
```

**HeroCardDialog**

```
public class HeroCardDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        //Set the Last Dialog in Conversation Data
        context.UserData.SetValue("HeroCardId", "HerdoCard Dialog");

        var message = context.MakeMessage();
        var attachment = GetHeroCard();

        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        await context.PostAsync((message));

        context.Done<object>(null);
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard()
    {
        var heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = "Hi!",
            Text = "Are you happy?",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Yes",
                        Text = "ShowGif",
                        DisplayText = null,
                        Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                        Value= "{\"msgback\" : \"ShowGif\"}"
                    },
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Meh...",
                        Text ="HappinessSearch",
                        DisplayText = null,
                        Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                        Value= "{\"msgback\" : \"HappinessSearch\"}"
                    }
                }

        };

        return heroCard.ToAttachment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostBack` is not supported by Microsoft Teams. Please check the list of [supported button activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-cards#buttons) in Microsoft Teams.

We recommend that you use `messageBack` as you can create a fully customized action.

Comment: I have modified my code to `Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,` but still it doesn't work. Now nothing happens. The chatbot doesn't react at all to my clicks. The  method 'MessageReceivedAsync' is not being called. Could you please provide a sample?

Comment: I can't find anything obviously wrong with your code after looking at it for a while, but here's an example that works: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/master/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/basic/HeroCardDialog.cs

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Thank you for commenting back and the link. I am checking the code but I still don't know how to catch the answer to the dialog. I updated my question with the new code.