# Hero card as choice prompt not working on Teams Mobile - Bot Framework(Waterfall Dialog)

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a waterfall dialog that uses choice prompts to ask users some questions, I have wrapped these choice up as hero cards like below:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing }, cancellationToken);

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(p1, new PromptOptions
        {
            Choices = new List<Choice>(){new Choice {Value = "650"},new Choice {Value = "600"},new Choice {Value = "Cancel"},},
            Prompt = ChoiceToCard(),
            Style = ListStyle.None, 
        });
}
private Activity ChoiceToCard()
{
    HeroCard card = new HeroCard
    {
        Text = "Please choose an option.",
        Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    };

    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction()
    {
        Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
        Title = "Option 1",
        Text = "650",
        DisplayText = "Option 1",
        Value = "650"
    });
    
    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction()
    {
        Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
        Title = "Option 2",
        Text = "600",
        DisplayText = "Option 2",
        Value = "600"
    });

    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction()
    {
        Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
        Title = "Cancel",
        Text = "Cancel",
        DisplayText = "Cancel",
        Value = "Cancel"
    });

    return MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()) as Activity;
}
```

This works fine when it runs on the Desktop Client of teams but when I click a button on the mobile client nothing happens, I don't see any errors in the logs, and as soon as I click the button on the desktop client then I receive a response.

The reason for doing this is because I have some id's/hidden values that are applied to the card button value to not expose this to the client view.

**UPDATE**

A few people have suggested a similar question, but this is where we need to understand that the cases are not the same, as the context that I have given differs from the suggestion.

This happens within a waterfall dialog, that uses a choice prompt to display the hero card to the user, and the reason for doing this and not just using the choice prompt Style is because I assign an id to the action value which should be passed back to my server instead of the user friendly text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chatbot not sending message back in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297536/chatbot-not-sending-message-back-in-microsoft-teams)

Comment: You can use adaptive cards instead of Hero cards in MS Team and I think MessageBack is not supported in MS Teams

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth No that link does not solve my problem, and also messageBack is supported as per the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=csharp

Comment: It seems like a bug, can you confirm on which platform you are facing it, iOS or Android?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Android

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT it looks like the value property of the action needs to be set to a complex type, and not simple type like string or int. but this does not seem consistent

Answer (score 0):

We have raised a bug, I can't share ETA but I will update once it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to the issue so I can give more info if needed

Comment: Sorry, I don't have public link to share. Let me know here only if you find something.